# Bidimensional Array and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I have a problem with this code: I don't know how to pass the reference to the matrix in the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct detA{
    int** matrix;
    int flag;
    int result;
};

void* det3x3 (void* arguments){

    struct detA* tmp = (struct detA *) arguments;

    if(tmp->flag){
        /*Quando il flag è uno sono nel thread A*/
        tmp->result = (tmp->matrix[0][0] * tmp->matrix[1][1] * tmp->matrix[2][2]) +
                        (tmp->matrix[0][1] * tmp->matrix[1][2] * tmp->matrix[2][0]) +
                        (tmp->matrix[0][2] * tmp->matrix[1][0] * tmp->matrix[2][1]);

        return (void*)&(tmp->result);
    }
    else{
        /*Quando il flag è zero sono nel thread B*/
        tmp->result = (tmp->matrix[2][0] *tmp->matrix[1][1] * tmp->matrix[0][2]) +
                        (tmp->matrix[2][1] * tmp->matrix[1][2] * tmp->matrix[0][0]) +
                        (tmp->matrix[2][2] * tmp->matrix[1][0] * tmp->matrix[0][1]);

        return (void*)&(tmp->result);
    }

}

int main(){

    pthread_t t1_id;
    pthread_t t2_id;

    int* t1_returnValue;
    int* t2_returnValue;

    int A [3][3] = {{1,1,1}, {1,1,1}, {1,1,1}};

    struct detA t1_args;
    struct detA t2_args;

    t1_args.matrix = A;
    t1_args.flag = 1;

    t2_args.matrix = A;
    t2_args.flag = 0;

    pthread_create(&t1_id, NULL, &det3x3, &t1_args);
    pthread_create(&t2_id, NULL, &det3x3, &t2_args);

    pthread_join(t1_id, (void**)&t1_returnValue);
    pthread_join(t2_id, (void**)&t2_returnValue);

    int det = (*t1_returnValue) - (*t2_returnValue);
    printf("Il determinante della matrice è: %d", det);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code i get an error when assign a matrix to int**.
What could it be? In a previous exercise I did the same with a normal array by putting an int * in the struct and it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare matrix `A` in memory what happens is that continuous memory is allocated to store all elements of the matrix. Therefore, you want to convert to `int*` because you are given a pointer to the memory location of matrix `A`. Whereas `int**` is a pointer to a location of pointers. Meaning that when it is dereferenced, the memory location you are at holds an array of pointers that can be dereferenced again. However, this is not the case in the above code. When dereferenced you are taken directly to where your elements are in memory rather than a location for an array of pointers.

Comment: So in the struct i need a `int*` ? Because i've already tried that

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Comment: But still don't work :(
I get this error 
`es3.c:25:38: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   25 |         tmp->result = (tmp->matrix[0][0] * tmp->matrix[1][1] * tmp->matrix[2][2]) +`

Answer (score 0):

The decaying of an array to a pointer only happens for the outermost dimension of a multidimensional array.

This means that an array of type `int [3][3]` does not decay to a `int **` but to a `int (*)[3]` i.e. a pointer to an array of size 3 of `int`.  So this is the type you should use for the `matrix` member of `struct detA`:

```
struct detA{
    int (*matrix)[3];
    int flag;
    int result;
};
```

Comment: I changed it and still give compiling error. Now the compiler say that there is no member named ''matrix'' or ''flag'' in the struct.

Comment: @ToniGun You probably have a typo.  The member should be declared as `int (*matrix)[3];`